# Could not find gem 'uglifier'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, server

I tried running:

```
rails g controller hello welcome
```

and got this error:

```
Could not find gem 'uglifier (>= 1.0.3) x86-mingw32' in any of the gem sour
ces listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I'm using Rails 2.2.5.

Comment: Like the error says, run bundle install... .

Answer (score 1):

First install gem successfully so you need to run below command:

```
  bundle install
```

If  all gem dependencies install successfully then you can create you can create your controller.